# How do I bind json Array data to html() in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on mvc5 I want to bind data to div using `.html(data)`

```
.done(function (data) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    $("mydata").html(result);
});
```

```html
<div id="mydata"></div>
```

Object data has values like following.

[image]

How do I bind values into `$("mydata")`?

I tried like above but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the response is coming back in JSON format then jQuery will have already deserialised it to an object for you. Calling `parseJSON` on the resulting object will cause an error.

Also, you are trying to set an object as the HTML value of an element which will result in the text `[Object object]` being shown. Instead you need to access the properties of that object.

Try this:

```
.done(function (data) {
    $("#mydata").html(data[0].Address); // will show 'pune'
});
```

Also note that your selector is missing the `#` - assuming that you are selecting by `id`.

Comment: jQuery ID selector... `$("#mydata")`

Comment: @Edgar good catch. I assume that's just a typo the OP made in the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Watch shows correct value but not displayed in  div :O 
strange why so ? not binding `pune` value to given `div`

Comment: @anish as Edgar says, you selector should be `$('#mydata')` - assuming you're selecting by `id`.

Comment: Damn it ! small mistake how can I do so hurry :( 
thanks